# SingleChildScrollView not working in Column

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am building an app facing a singleChildScrollView not able to scroll the page the text has been cut from bottom after the contact button i want to scroll the page but but spending so much time can't fix problem.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCUqq.jpg)

```
enter code here

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
```

class DetailScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final electricain;

DetailScreen(this.electricain);

@override
  _DetailScreenState createState() => _DetailScreenState();
}

```
    class _DetailScreenState extends State<DetailScreen> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
     body: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3 + 20,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Stack(
                  fit: StackFit.expand,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.asset(
                      'assets/images/detail_bg.jpg',
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                      color: Colors.purple.withOpacity(0.1),
                    ),



                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: 50,
                left: 20,
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3.6 - 40,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(60),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                          child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 130,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Description',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 20,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 10,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              '${widget.electricain['desc']}',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                              ),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 10,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "\n Services List",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 10),
                            Text(
                              '${widget.electricain['services']}',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 30),
                            MaterialButton(
                              onPressed: () {},
                              color: Colors.orange,
                              child: Text(
                                "Contact",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16.0),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 10),
                            Text(
                              '${widget.electricain['services']}',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3 - 90,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
                  child: Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3 - 20,
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 6 + 20,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: widget.electricain['bgColor'],
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        ),
                        child: Stack(
                          fit: StackFit.expand,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Positioned(
                              top: 10,
                              right: -25,
                              child: Image.asset(
                                widget.electricain['imgUrl'],
                                scale: 1.7,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 20,
                      ),
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            widget.electricain['electricainName'],
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 20,
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            widget.electricain['shopName'],
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                              color: Colors.grey,
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 10,
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Icon(
                                Icons.star,
                                size: 16,
                                color: Color(0xffFF8573),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(width: 5),
                              Text(
                                widget.electricain['rating'],
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color(0xffFF8573),
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 5,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                '(${widget.electricain['rateAmount']})',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```dart
LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
              child: ConstrainedBox(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: constraints.maxWidth, minHeight: constraints.maxHeight),
                  child: IntrinsicHeight(
                    child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          //your children here
                        ]
                    ),
                  )
              )
          );
        })
```

IntrinsicHeight class

A widget that sizes its child to the child's intrinsic height.

This class is useful, for example, when unlimited height is available and you would like a child that would otherwise attempt to expand infinitely to instead size itself to a more reasonable height.